# How to create input type = date in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to use DateInput from http://jquerytools.org/demos/dateinput/index.html

The demo on their website is clear, I can replicate it on my machine.

The problem now arises in that I am using MVC4 and need to use the 'For' (eg TextBoxFor) helpers...

There is no DateBoxFor

using MVC and the Model. In my head, I'd need something like

```
 @Html.DateBoxFor(a => a.BillStartDate, new { @class = "width400" })
```

or (where the last parameter is the type)

```
  @Html.GenericBoxFor(a => a.BillStartDate, new { @class = "width400" }, "Date")
```

How can I replicate

```
<input type="date" />
```

Comment: @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.BillStartDate, new { @class = "width400", type = "date" }) Doesn't this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing it into the `htmlAttributes`, like you did with the `class`:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.BillStartDate, new { @class = "width400", type="date" }
```

Answer (score 2):

You were close in your thinking:

```
@Html.DateBoxFor(a => a.BillStartDate, new { @class = "width400" })
```

Becomes

```
@Html.TextboxFor(a => a.BillStartDate, new { @class = "width400", type = "date" })
```

Comment: No need for the `@type`.

Comment: Good catch. Copy and paste strikes again.